# How to schedule a task in C++

Tags: c++, windows, scheduling

I have a C++ windows service which should call a function every 15 minutes. I am new to c++ and have no idea how to do this.Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Subrat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906.aspx).

Alternately, use the [Task Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446802.aspx), which can execute a regular `.exe` or COM handler on a predefined schedule. If you do that, you may not even need a service.

Comment: +1 No need to bring in Boost for such a simple, platform-specific need.

Comment: How do i use task scheduler? I checked the MSDN articles. They are not very clear. I want to execute a .exe. How do i specify the address while activating?

Comment: @Subrat: Here is a tutorial for the Task Scheduler 2.0 API (Vista and higher): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163350.aspx. If you need XP support, you will want to look at the older 1.0 API. Here are some examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383579.aspx.

Comment: I created an scheduler in C++.I have set all the parameters and the task is configured to run only when the user is logged on with the user name provided(Done by setting the TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON flag).

When I try to run the task I get a status "Could not start". Now suppose I manually edit any property in task property and click on OK the task runs fine.

Note:The manual edit specified may be anything, like just adding a space at the end of the excecutable name or the user name. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

There are many libraries to provid timers.

What operating system and what libraries are you using? You could implement one by yourself using [Boost::Timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/timer/index.html) (or even standard C time-related functions from `ctime` header), or, if you're using a library that handles the main loop, it for sure provides some functions.

Comment: This may be a silly question :).The files there have .hpp extension. what are they? can i use it in my code? My files have .cpp extension.

Comment: They are header files for C++. You can use them just like classical header files with `.h` extension: just include them with `#include <HEADER.hpp>`

Comment: Found this in Boost documentation. Dont think i can use it.                                                              The maximum measurable elapsed time may be as low as 596.5 hours (or even less) for the supplied implementation. Because of these limitations, this timer cannot be depended upon to be robust, and should not be used if that is of any concern.

Comment: @Subrat: for sure a timer of 15 minutes will work whenever. Anyway I think that using Boost::Timer is the right way to follow for most cases; if you have some very special needs for some exotic systems, you should re-implement your timer routines only for such systems (using macro conditions: `#ifdef`) using system-specific calls that give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is `<ctime>` header in C++ (`<time.h>` in C)   which provides some basic low-level time functionality. However if you are seeking something more close to c#'s timer then you can use Qt's `QTimer` class. Get to know [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) - it's a good thing.

Comment: `Qt` is good, but if this is for a company, you have to know that `Qt` is not free.

Comment: It's been almost two years since Qt LGPL switch.